# How to temporarily convert pandas df to lower case for duplicates check? Then revert to normal afterwards

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I am dropping duplicates from a dataframe based on firstname, lastname, email and saving to a new df called df_unique.

I've converted everything to lower case and removed whitespace so the fields to increase the chances of a match. Note that index 0 and 2 are the same but won't be picked up without converting to lower.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'firstname':['foo Bar','Bar Bar','Foo Bar'],'lastname':['Foo Bar','Bar','Foo Bar'],'email':['Foo bar','Bar','Foo Bar']})

df

  firstname lastname    email
0   foo Bar  Foo Bar  Foo bar
1   Bar Bar      Bar      Bar
2   Foo Bar  Foo Bar  Foo Bar

#remove NAs
#convert to lower
#remove whitespace
#drop dupes


df_unique = (df.dropna(subset=['firstname', 'lastname', 'email'])
.applymap(lambda s:s.lower() if type(s) == str else s)
.applymap(lambda x: x.replace(" ", "") if type(x)==str else x)
.drop_duplicates(subset=['firstname', 'lastname', 'email']))


df_unique

  firstname lastname   email
0    foobar   foobar  foobar
1    barbar      bar     bar
```

However, the records are permanently lowercase now, and double names like `Foo Bar` are now `foobar`.

How can I do this without permanently changing the data?

I've tried using .copy() in the middle of all that but it just got too messy and broke things.

Is there a better way to do this?

edit:

With a bit of tweaking of @shaik moeeds answer below, I managed to get something working.

Here I get the index of unique records:

```
uniq_indx = (df.dropna(subset=['firstname', 'lastname', 'email'])
.applymap(lambda s:s.lower() if type(s) == str else s)
.applymap(lambda x: x.replace(" ", "") if type(x)==str else x)
.drop_duplicates(subset=['firstname', 'lastname', 'email'])).index
```

Then use this to index the DF and save the unique records:

```
df_unique = df.loc[uniq_indx]
```

I also wanted to keep the duplicate records, so used drop() and the index from above to remove the uniques:

```
df_duplicates = df.drop(uniq_indx)
```

This seems to work on checking the outputs, however if there are any mistakes please let me know.

Comment: It won't pick up duplicates with different cases. `'Foo Bar'` and `'foo Bar'` are the same, but this won't pick it up. I have to convert to lowercase first.

Comment: `duplicated()` is case sensitive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can continue with your code, with small modification. Use the `.index` values of duplicates, to get original format.

Like this,

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'firstname':['Foo Bar','Foo Bar','Bar Bar','Foo Bar'],
                       'lastname' :['Foo Bar','Foo Bar', 'Bar','Foo Bar'],
                       'email'    :['Foo Bar','Foo Bar', 'Bar','Foo Bar']})

>>> df.iloc[(df.dropna(subset=['firstname', 'lastname', 'email'])
.applymap(lambda s:s.lower() if type(s) == str else s)
.applymap(lambda x: x.replace(" ", "") if type(x)==str else x)
.drop_duplicates(subset=['firstname', 'lastname', 'email'])).index]
```

---

**Output:**

```
  firstname lastname    email
0   Foo Bar  Foo Bar  Foo Bar
2   Bar Bar      Bar      Bar
```

Comment: Seems to work for the dummy DF here, but not my full dataset. I had to tweak yours a bit. Can't fit the code in here so edited my original question. I ended up using loc instead of iloc.. don't know why that works instead of the other. Could you have a quick look and sense check it?

Comment: @SCool it is working because your label's of index are `integers` in actual `df`. It's prefer to use `.iloc` as we are using `index` values. Hope this clears your doubts.

Comment: @SCool Why you need `df_duplicates`? Is it really necessary? Think once.

Comment: I need to save the duplicates for manual review. This is for work.

Comment: @SCool Okay, You can use as mentioned in question. If this is helpful, don't forget to accept.

Answer (score 0):

Look for the index values of your duplicates and drop the rows.

```
df.drop(
    index=(
        pd.concat(
            g for _, g in df.dropna(subset=["firstname", "lastname", "email"])
            .applymap(lambda s: s.lower() if type(s) == str else s)
            .applymap(lambda x: x.replace(" ", "") if type(x) == str else x)
            .groupby(["firstname", "lastname", "email"])
            if len(g) > 1
        )
    ).index
)
```

Output:

```
  firstname lastname email
1   Bar Bar      Bar   Bar
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df_unique = df[df.applymap(str).applymap(str.lower).applymap(str.strip).duplicated() == False]
```